# Failed to create API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create this API Gateway ([gist](https://gist.github.com/nguyendviet/79994bdbb380e43e7d08b07d007705d3)) with Authorizer, and ANY method.

I run into this error:

```sh
The following resource(s) failed to create: [BaseLambdaExecutionPolicy, ApiGatewayDeployment]
```

I've checked the parameters passed into this template from my other stacks and they're correct. I've checked this template and it's valid.

My template is modified from this [template](https://github.com/markhopson/cloudformation-serverless-api) with `"Runtime": "nodejs8.10"`.

This is the same stack ([gist](https://gist.github.com/nguyendviet/ace3a903dddc57952dbd49ddf2870d08)) which is created successfully using `swagger 2`. I just want to replace `swagger 2` with `AWS::ApiGateway::Method`.

> Update 6 Jun 2019:

I tried to create the whole nested stack using the working version of the API Gateway stack, then create another API Gateway with the template that doesn't work with the parameters I get from the nested stack, then I have this:

```sh
The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: ID)
```

But I did specify the method in my template following [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html):

```
"GatewayMethod": {
            "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
            "DependsOn": ["LambdaRole", "ApiGateway"],
            "Properties" : {
                "ApiKeyRequired" : false,
                "AuthorizationType" : "Cognito",
                "HttpMethod" : "ANY",
                "Integration" : {
                    "IntegrationHttpMethod" : "ANY",
                    "Type" : "AWS",
                    "Uri" : {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations"
                    }
                },
                "MethodResponses" : [{
                    "ResponseModels": {
                      "application/json": "Empty"
                    },
                    "StatusCode": 200
                }],
                "RequestModels" : {"application/json": "Empty"},
                "ResourceId" : {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["ApiGateway", "RootResourceId"] 
                },
                "RestApiId" : {
                    "Ref": "ApiGateway"
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: You should probably go back to the version that worked, then add one resource at a time to figure out which resource causes the error.

Comment: Presumably the stack events will give you more information about why it failed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for your suggestion, that's what I'm trying to do: create the nested stack with the version that worked and pass in the parameters for the version that doesn't work. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: @404: unfortunately, that's all it shows me for that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @John's suggestion. I've tried to create the nested stack with the version that worked and pass in the parameters for the version that doesn't work.

The reason for that error is:

> CloudFormation might try to create Deployment before it creates Method

from **balaji**'s answer [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232074).

So this is what I did:

```
"methodANY": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
            "Properties": {
              "AuthorizationType": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
...},
"ApiGatewayDeployment": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
            "DependsOn": "methodANY",
...
```

I also found [this article on cloudonaut.io by Michael Wittig](https://cloudonaut.io/api-gateway-custom-authorization-with-lambda-dynamodb-and-cloudformation/) helpful.